# Swift Realm class type in function as parameter

Tags: swift, xcode, function, parameters, realm

I have the following class for my Realm database:

```
class Advert: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name: String?
    @objc dynamic var price: String?
    @objc dynamic var detail: String?
    @objc dynamic var category: String?
    @objc dynamic var date: String?
}
```

I want to pass my property into the parameters of a function but Advert.Any is of course not working:

```
func updateAdvert(index: Int, attribute: Advert.Any, newValue: Any ) {
        let result = realm.objects(Advert.self)[index]
        
        try! realm.write {
            switch attribute{
            case .name:
                result.name = newValue as! String
            case .price:
                result.price = newValue as! String
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't use realm. Is `result` an `NSObject` by any chance? Check by doing `result as NSObject`, and if you don't get an error such as '`* is not convertible to 'NSObject'`', then it is.

Comment: let result = realm.objects(Advert.self)[index] as NSObject

Comment: It is working. So I guess it is a NSObject

Comment: @George All objects in Realm are based on NSObject and bridged to Swift.

Comment: Don't do this `let result = realm.objects(Advert.self)[index]` as Realm is unordered unless you specify the order - e.g. index could resolve to different objects at different times. Only Lists are guaranteed order unless you use a sort function when retrieving from Realm. Also, since you know the property you want to modify, just modify it! No need for a function call: `myObject.name = "some name"`

Comment: Oh - if you're using Realm 10.10, you can use the [.map](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/data-types/map/) property type as well like this `someAdvert.mapToName.setValue("some name", forKey: "name")` where mapToName is a Map property in the Advert object.